# What are the 8 rules for 8 Mask patterns for QR code?

Tags: qr-code

I was making some QR code manually and I'm stuck in the Data Masking part of making the QR code.

The section where I became confused is underlined as shown in the picture below, saying that there are 8 rules for each masking pattern for QR code.

[image]

The website where I read the Data Making pattern is here:

https://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/data-masking

The rules to create the first and second masking pattern for a QR code has been stated, namely:

For **mask pattern #1**, every even - numbered row in the QR matrix is masked.

For **mask pattern #2**, every third column in the QR matrix is masked.

The third to eighth masking patterns weren't stated and I wasn't able to find it when googled. The rules are applicable to particular masking pattern and there were eight rules, so there are eight masking pattern to be created.

My question is:

*What are the 8 rules for 8 Mask patterns for QR code?*

Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be a little late, but I was doing the same thing, and found this image on Wikipedia:
[image]

Comment: hi @OliverF ! Where did you get those Images?

Comment: @LalakiugBabaye, I found the image above at https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:QR_Code_Mask_Patterns.svg, and another useful one can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#/media/File:QR_Format_Information.svg

Comment: Are there any web apps or downloadable QR code generating software/apps that utilize user-selected masking options? I have never found any.